# Time based algorithm to make object orbit another in electron-type path?

Tags: trigonometry, circles

I'm positioning an object in 3d space, and I want to make it orbit another object, in a semi-random electron-like orbit, such that it always stays the same distance from the origin. I can make it move in a circle easy enough from high school math:

```
x: sin( time ),
y: cos( time ),
z: 0
```

But I'm not sure what the right algorithm is to make correctly orbit the object in a spherical, zig-zaggy electron type path.

**Edit2** The back story is I'm testing the effect of a light on a sphere in 3d space. I want the light to orbit the sphere in a pattern that eventually covers most of the surface, so it can't just orbit in a circle. I would like it to orbit in a smooth, visually pleasing path.

**Edit3**: What I actually want is to make the point follow the path of a circle on a plane, then spin the plane orthogonally.

Comment: I would personally recommend randomness; that seems to be what you want. How about you decide what the direction the object goes every second or so randomly?

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about your requirements. So you want the orbit to be a continuous path, but random in direction?

Comment: @StretchManiac no, I want it to be smooth. Assume the child is orbiting in a circle (on a plane), as described above. Now, move the child up and down (perpendicular to the circle)  in a sine wave motion, so that it sort of spirals around the object, always keeping the same distance from the origin.

Comment: Added 2 edits @ChristopherA.Wong

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I think you are looking for the [spherical coordinate system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html) (this also tells you how to convert back to Cartesian coordinates).

The radius is r, and should be constant so that all the points are "on the sphere".

An example I came up with [with this](http://www.flashandmath.com/mathlets/multicalc/paramsphere/surf_graph_sphere.html):

[image]

$r=1$
$\phi = \frac{s}{10}$
$\theta = s$

You could also do something like this:

[image]

$r=1$
$\phi = \frac{\pi}{2}+1.1sin(6s)$
$\theta = s$

The quality is horrendous (I sooooooo wish I had Mathematica), but you get the idea.

These aren't random, but they cover most of the surface area.

Good Luck!